# measuring work function of particles on insulating sample

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am looking for methods to estimate the work function of Cu oxide nanoparticles which are dispersed on an insulating alumina support. It appears that the insulating alumina will cause charge buildup during UV photoelectron spectroscopy making comparison between samples difficult. Any suggestions as to other methods or charge compensating techniques are highly welcome.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the charge buildup will affect the potential. If you can negatively charge the sample, then determine the leakage rate as a function of wavelength (by measuring the current with varying wavelength), I wonder if you can determine the wavelength needed to get the "last electron off". I admit I never had to try...